# Using Rollup to only convert to CommonJS, without bundling

Tags: javascript, rollupjs

What's the best way to work around this problem outlined below?

...or should I be using something other than Rollup for this task?

...

Suppose I'm developing a library foo which exposes two es6 modules `a.js` and `b.js` (i.e. to allow `import a from foo/a` and `import b from foo/b`)

**Source es6 modules**

```
// src/a.js
export default function a(x) { return x+'!' }
```

...

```
// src/b.js
import a from './a.js'
export default function b() { return a('Hi') }
```

I then want to convert both a.js and b.js into CommonJs modules and save them in the project's root folder. So effectively I want the line `import a from './a'` only turned into `const a = require('./a')` and skip any bundling. Like so:

**Desired CommonJS output**

```
// a.js
module.exports = function a(x) { return x+'!' }
```

...

```
// b.js
const a = require('./a')
module.exports = function b() { return a('Hi') }
```

My first instinct is to use something like `external: (id) => id!==currentFile`, in rollup.config.js to define all the sibling modules as external. That **almost works** but results in the relative import path being rewritten to `const a = require('./src/a')` (importing the es6-version of `a.js` from the `src` folder).

**Actual result**

```
// a.js
module.exports = function a(x) { return x+'!' }
```

...

```
// b.js
const a = require('./src/a')
module.exports = function b() { return a('Hi') }
```

Comment: So essentially you are getting an extra `/src` which you don't want?

Comment: Yes. Rollup treats the "external" module path as a fixed target and therefore the exported CommonJS module requires the es6 version of `a.js`

Comment: Can you give a sample repo with the rollup config, I want to make sure that I debug this with being on same page with you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
// rollup.config.js
export default {
    input: ['src/a.js', 'src/b.js'],
    output: {
        dir: '.',
        format: 'cjs'
    },
    experimentalCodeSplitting: true,
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Somehow it feels almost like an unintended side-effect of the `experimentalCodeSplitting`, but it works - apart from some extra cruft-injection caused by what looks like a bug in the code-splitting functionality. (I will raise that issue on Github).

Comment: I don't really think that's a side-effect (dont confuse experimentalCodeSplitting with experimentalDynamicImports), its more like a hack to pass multiple input files to rollup and get them with the same name as output

Answer (score 0):

It is also worth mentioning `rollup`'s `resolveId` hook, because it allows you finer control over exclusion as well as the replacement import path.  From the [rollup doc](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#hooks):

> resolveId
>
> Type: (source: string, importer: string) => string | false | null |
>   {id: string, external?: boolean, moduleSideEffects?: boolean | null}
>   Kind: async, first
>
> Defines a custom resolver. A resolver can be useful for e.g. locating
>   third-party dependencies. Returning null defers to other resolveId
>   functions and eventually the default resolution behavior; returning
>   false signals that source should be treated as an external module and
>   not included in the bundle. If this happens for a relative import, the
>   id will be renormalized the same way as when the external option is
>   used.
>
> If you return an object, then it is possible to resolve an import to a
>   different id while excluding it from the bundle at the same time. This
>   allows you to replace dependencies with external dependencies without
>   the need for the user to mark them as "external" manually via the
>   external option:

```
resolveId(source) {
  if (source === 'my-dependency') {
    return {id: 'my-dependency-develop', external: true};
  }
  return null;
}
```

> Relative ids, i.e. starting with ./ or ../, will not be renormalized
>   when returning an object. If you want this behaviour, return an
>   absolute file system location as id instead.
>
> If false is returned for moduleSideEffects in the first hook that
>   resolves a module id and no other module imports anything from this
>   module, then this module will not be included without checking for
>   actual side-effects inside the module. If true is returned, Rollup
>   will use its default algorithm to include all statements in the module
>   that have side-effects (such as modifying a global or exported
>   variable). If null is returned or the flag is omitted, then
>   moduleSideEffects will be determined by the
>   treeshake.moduleSideEffects option or default to true. The load and
>   transform hooks can override this.